# Making a secure connection to a SQL database in php

Tags: php, sql, security, connection

I am trying to make secure my database credentials but they keep showing up in the firebug console.

I simply want to save form information into a database.

My form (form.html)

```
<form id="Form" method="POST" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input id="name" name="name" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Address:</td>
            <td><input id="address" name="address" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Telephone:</td>
            <td><input id="telephone" name="telephone" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td><input id="email" name="email" type="email" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="SubmitButton">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
    </form>

    <div id="Response"></div>
</div>

<!-- javascript to handle form data -->
<script type="text/javascript">    
$("document").ready(function(){
    var frm = $('#Form');
    frm.submit(function (ev) {      
        ev.preventDefault();  

        var email = $('#email').val();
       if(email)
       {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType:"json",
                url: "submit.php",
                data: frm.serialize(),
                success: function () {
                    $('#Response').empty();
                    $('#Response').wrapInner("<span class='SuccessMessage'>Your information has been submitted successfully!</span>")
                    return;
                },
                error: function () {
                 $('#Response').empty();
                 $('#Response').wrapInner("<span class='ErrorMessage'>Your information was not submitted successfully.  Please try again.</span>")
              }
            });
        } else {
            $('#Response').empty();
            $('#Response').wrapInner("<span class='EmailBlankMessage'>Email address is a required field.</span>")
            return;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is my submit.php

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    require(dirname(__FILE__)."/../config.php");

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $address = $_POST["address"];
    $telephone = $_POST["telephone"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];

    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
    $address = mysql_real_escape_string($address);
    $telephone = mysql_real_escape_string($telephone);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO XXXXX(name, address, telephone, email) VALUES('$name', '$address', '$address', '$email')"); 


}else { 
    header("Location: /Form.html");
    die();
}
```

?>

Here is my config.php

```
 <?

$hostname = "XXXXXX";
$database = "XXXXXX";
$username = "XXXXXX";
$password = "XXXXXX";

mysql_connect($hostname, $username , $password) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database ) or die (mysql_error());
```

The config file is placed outside the root.  However the 2 main issues I am having is that it won't insert the form data into the table and also the database credentials from config.php show up in the firebug console post response.  I don't understand what is wrong with my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your php open tag in `config.php` is `<?` - this is [short open tag](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag), which I think is disabled in your config. Your php in `config.php` is then not interpreted and is shown as is. Change it to regular open tag `<?php`.

Also note that `mysql` extension is deprecated, you should switch to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and prepared statements.